# Bootstrap DateTimePicker - How to disable hour of one day

Tags: javascript, php, datetimepicker

I have a problem with Bootstrap DateTimePicker.
In database (MysQl), I have a dates, when I met with client. For example:
ID, Datatime
1. 2017-10-26 10:00
2. 2017-11-01 11:00

How can I disable this(and other dates from database) hours on days specified in the database in DateTimePicker?

Here I have PHP code, for download dates and hours form database:

```php
<?php
     include ("dbconfig.php");
    $conn->select_db("zapis");
    try{
       $js_ddates = "";
       $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT termin_k FROM klient_zapisany");
       while($record = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
          $js_ddates .= '' .($record['termin_k'] . '';
       }
    }?>
```

And now JS code with datapicker:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:ii:ss",
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'pl',
    locale: 'pl',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,7],
    todayBtn: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
    minuteStep: 10
  });
  $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker('setHoursDisabled', [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,22,23 ]);

});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From doc, malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker, it looks like it does *not* provide options for that out of the box. If you code it, I am sure the author will be very happy for your submission!

Comment: But i don't have idea how to write this code. Can you help me?